# Undefined variable $key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-8

This is my AssignmentController Store function. (This is my AssignmentController Store function.) This is my AssignmentController Store function. (This is my AssignmentController Store function.)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(array(
        'assignment' => 'array|required',
        'assignment.*.staff_id' => 'required',
        'assignment.*.task_id' => 'required',
        'done_at' => 'sometimes',
    ));

    foreach($request->get('assignment') as $assignment)

        $assignment = Assignment::create(array(
            'staff_id' => $assignment['staff_id'],
            'task_id' => $assignment['task_id'],
            'done_at' => $assignment['done_at'],
        ));



        return redirect()->route('assignments.index')->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

This is my assignment.create page (This is my assignment.create page This is my assignment.create page )

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('assignments.store')}}">
        @csrf
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Task Title : </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="assignment[{{$key}}][task_id] " id="task_id">
                            {{-- <option value="">Select One</option> --}}
                            @foreach ($tasks as $task)

                                <option value="{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->title }}</option>

                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Staff Name : </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="assignment[{{$key}}][staff_id]" id="staff_id" multiple>
                            {{-- <option value="">Select One</option> --}}
                            @foreach ($staffs as $staff)

                                <option value="{{ $staff->id }}">{{ $staff->name }}</option>

                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Done At :</td>
                    <td><input type="time" name="done_at" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: you just need to change `return redirect()->route('assignments.index', compact('assignment'))->withSuccess('Done');`

Comment: I try this but showing "Undefined variable $key"

Comment: In your controller in create method you have to return view with key `return view('assignment.create',["key"=>$key]);`

Answer (score 1):

You should pass $key variable to 'assignment.create' page.If you have a controller function for loading 'assignment.create' page, pass $key variable to the view through that function.